# Prometheus Trigger Single Alert if set of nodes are down

Tags: prometheus, prometheus-alertmanager

I have the below targets configured on my prometheus server. All servers are configured in Target1.yml file and Router details are stored in Router.yml file. Each site has unique 4 digit numbers and in this example it is "**1234**". So like this we have 1000's of sites *(in total 1000*5 nodes)*. Whenever a router goes down or if we have a power outage we are getting 5 alerts in total for each site.

**Target1.yml**:

```
node1-1234.example.com
node2-1234.example.com
node3-1234.example.com
node1-4567.example.com
node2-4567.example.com
node3-4567.example.com
```

**Router.yml**:

```
router1-1234.example.com
router2-1234.example.com
router1-4567.example.com
router2-4567.example.com
```

I am looking for a solution to trigger only router alerts when there is a power outage ignoring the node1/node2/node3. Can you please help on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seem you can use https://github.com/prometheus/blackbox_exporter or https://github.com/czerwonk/ping_exporter

Then create alert rules based on the exported metrics

Example prometheus rules using blackbox exporter https://awesome-prometheus-alerts.grep.to/rules#blackbox-1